# Why do we use sub $0x18, %rsp?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I studied 32 bit machine, and I know sub $12, %esp as same as three time on pop %eax and mov $0, %eax.

But I don't know why we use add $18, %rsp with start procedure call or sub $18, %rsp start with procedure call at x86-64 machine.

Why does compiler use this rule for procedure call? Argument rule?

```
0x0000000000400df3 <main+191>:  mov    $0x402227,%edi
0x0000000000400df8 <main+196>:  callq  0x400ab8 <puts@plt>
0x0000000000400dfd <main+201>:  callq  0x4014c0 <read_line>
0x0000000000400e02 <main+206>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000000000400e05 <main+209>:  callq  0x401139 <phase_3>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
example:

0x0000000000401139 <example+0>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x000000000040113d <example+4>: lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401142 <example+9>: lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
0x0000000000401147 <example+14>:        mov    $0x40248a,%esi
0x000000000040114c <example+19>:        mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000401151 <example+24>:        callq  0x400ac8 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x0000000000401156 <example+29>:        cmp    $0x1,%eax
```

Comment: What does your function look like?

Comment: Your question deserves a downvote by the difference between 0x18 and 18. :)

Comment: See. I didn't ask for the code for no reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"I know `sub $12, %esp` as same as three time on `pop %eax` and `mov $0, %eax`." You know wrong. `sub $12, %esp` does not change `eax`, neither by popping into it nor by moving a 0 into it.

The primary/direct reason for using something like `sub $12, %esp` is to reserve some space on the stack. That can be used to give some space to local variables of a subroutine. That can also be used to align the stack pointer if it's desirable for performance or other reasons.

`add $18, %rsp` does the reverse, it releases the space previously allocated on the stack. This can be used to free the space occupied by local variables or by the parameters that have been previously passed to another subroutine and aren't needed on the stack anymore.

Comment: Why don't we use sub $16, %rsp? Isn't it x86-64 virtual memory which word is 8byte?

Comment: You didn't show us the code, so how would we know why it's 18 or something else and it's correct?

Comment: I mean that rsp grows by 8? What advantage of using add or subtract $18?

Comment: In 64-bit mode you cannot push/pop directly a 4-byte entity, but you can an 8-byte one and ... a 2-byte one. Surprise. There could be some 16-bit push/pop, but what more can I say without seeing the code?

Comment: You freely mix up decimal and hexadecimal notation of numbers. This is as source of errors.